# Preventing Thread Specific Data From Being Overwritten C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to create a simple chat program in C. For each client, I am creating a new thread so the server can handle communicating with multiple users at once. I am storing each user data in a stucture as follows:

```
struct User                     /*structure to handle all clients*/
{
    int port;
    char username[10];
    struct User*connected;
    struct User*next;
};
```

In the main thread, I create a new thread and pass in the structure for the user:

```
 pthread_create(&thr,NULL,server,(void*)&args);
```

This is done for each user.

Now, when each new thread is created, i copy the user structure from the arguments to be used in the thread.

```
   void *server(void * arguments) 
    {
          struct User*cur_user = arguments; 
    }
```

This works fine for the first user, however, when a new user joins, the information from the arguments is overwritten.

I understand that threads share data in a program. However, is there a way I can copy the arguments and same them to a local variable in the thread so they are only thread scope? In other words, how can I use the `cur_user`variable within the thread without having other threads modify its contents?

EDIT:

I tried to copy the memory but I am not having much luck:

```
struct User args;                     
        struct User*new_arg = malloc(sizeof(struct *new_arg));
        memcpy(new_arg, *args, sizeof(new_arg))
```

Is something wrong with my malloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is just a pointer. You're giving each thread a pointer to the same `args` structure. So they each have their own pointer but they all point to the same thing. Since they all then access the arguments through their pointer, they all access the same arguments.

You need to actually give each one of them their own structure, not just their own pointer to the same structure. Allocate a new structure with malloc(), fill it in, and hand it to the server/thread (which needs to free() it before it dies.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am having trouble allocating the new memory. I have added comments above

Comment: @AdamJakiela: Either `sizeof *new_arg` or `sizeof(struct User)`. I prefer the first. Also, assignment works, no need for memcpy. `*new_arg = arg;` is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can stomach `gcc`-specific solutions, consider [the `__thread` storage class](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html).

Otherwise, consider using [`pthread_key_create()`/`pthread_get_specific()`+`pthread_set_specific()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_key_create.html#tag_03_534_06) .